# Fuzzymatcher returns NaN for best_match_score

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, fuzzy-search

I'm observing odd behaviour while performing `fuzzy_left_join` from `fuzzymatcher` library. Trying to join two df, left one with 5217 records and right one with 8734, the all records with `best_match_score` is 71 records, which seems really odd . To achieve better results I even remove all the numbers and left only alphabetical charachters for joining columns. In the merged table the id column from the right table is `NaN`, which is also strange result.

left table - column for join "amazon_s3_name". First item - `limonig`

```
+------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------+
|  id  | product | price | category  |           amazon_s3_name           |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | A       |  1.49 | fruits    | limonig                            |
| 8964 | B       |  1.39 | beverages | studencajfuzelimonilimonetatrevaml |
| 9659 | C       |  2.79 | beverages | studencajfuzelimonilimtreval       |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------+
```

right table - column for join "amazon_s3_name" - last item - `limoni`

```
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|  id  |                                                       picture                                                              |                    amazon_s3_name          |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|  191 | https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/groceries.pictures/images/AhmadCajLimonIDjindjifil20X2G.jpg                          | ahmadcajlimonidjindjifilxg                 |
|  192 | https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/groceries.pictures/images/AhmadCajLimonIDjindjifil20X2G40g.jpg                       | ahmadcajlimonidjindjifilxgg                |
|  204 | https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/groceries.pictures/images/Ahmadcajlimonidjindjifil20x2g40g00051265.jpg               | ahmadcajlimonidjindjifilxgg                |
| 1608 | https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/groceries.pictures/images/Cajstudenfuzetealimonilimonovatreva15lpet.jpg              | cajstudenfuzetealimonilimonovatrevalpet    |
| 4689 | https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/groceries.pictures/images/Lesieursalatensosslimonimaslinovomaslo.jpg                 | lesieursalatensosslimonimaslinovomaslo     |
| 4690 | https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/groceries.pictures/images/Lesieursalatensosslimonimaslinovomaslo05l500ml01301150.jpg | lesieursalatensosslimonimaslinovomaslolml  |
| 4723 | https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/groceries.pictures/images/Limoni.jpg                                                 | limoni                                     |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

merged table - as we can see in the merged table `best_match_score` is `NaN`

```
+----+------------------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
| id | best_match_score | __id_left | __id_right | price | category | amazon_s3_name_left  | image_left | amazon_s3_name_left | image_right | amazon_s3_name_right |
+----+------------------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
|  0 | NaN              | 0_left    | None       |  1.49 | Fruits   | Limoni500g09700112   | NaN        | limonig             | NaN         | NaN                  |
|  2 | NaN              | 2_left    | None       |  1.69 | Bio      | Morkovi1kgbr09700132 | NaN        | morkovikgbr         | NaN         | NaN                  |
+----+------------------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, repoducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RJAdriaansen, I've added example.

Comment: Fuzzymatcher only really works where there are some tokens in common.  In this case the tokens will be splint on `/` but it'll be trying to match `limonig` to `AhmadCajLimonIDjindjifil20X2G`, so nothing will be found.  RJ's answer looks sensible.  Alternatively you'd need to somehow split the urls into smaller tokens

Comment: @RobinL why the fuzzymatcher will look into a column which is not specified as a column to merge on?

Comment: ah, my mistake. i was looking at the wrong column.    The same reasoning is still true - when fuzzyfinder attempts to find potential matches, it assumes that the input strings can be tokenised and that at least one token matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give [`polyfuzz`](https://pypi.org/project/polyfuzz/) a try. Use the examples' setup, for example using `TF-IDF` or `Bert`, then run:

```
model = PolyFuzz(matchers).match(df1["amazon_s3_name"].tolist(), df2["amazon_s3_name"].to_list())
df1['To'] = model.get_matches()['To']
```

then merge:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='To', right_on='amazon_s3_name')
```

Comment: running the porposed solution, still got no results, due to is really taking a lot of time

Comment: Unfortunately the output table do not consis of any matching score. In my case when I'm merging 5217 records with 8734 records, the final output is 92401. There is no way to choose the best match. On top of that the process took few hours.

Comment: Alternatively you could give [polyfuzz](https://pypi.org/project/polyfuzz/) a try. Use the examples' setup, for example using `TF-IDF` or `Bert`, then run `model = PolyFuzz(matchers).match(df1["amazon_s3_name"].tolist(), df2["amazon_s3_name"].to_list())`, `df1['To'] = model.get_matches()['To']`, then merge: `df1.merge(df2, left_on='To', right_on='amazon_s3_name')`

Comment: this was s great solution thank you. I think you should change you main answer with this solution so I could accept it